# Sending .wav files from Phone via email

Tags: file-transfer, sound

I have recorded some .wav files by using a free sound recording app. I want to be able to send these to others by email. The files show within the app as "soundfile-13.wav" for example. Can these be attached to email or transferred to my laptop? These files don't seem to appear when I search on the windows phone

Comment: What app are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's "Files" app, available from the Store, can do this.

Install and open "Files" and find your .wav file. Long press on the .wav file and select share. Select your email app from the list and it should create a new email with the file attached.

Comment: There's about a 1% chance that this will actually work since the vast majority of apps store data in their sandbox.

Comment: No, apparently it does work. The Files app is pretty useful as a file manager application

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps to share the recorded file.

1. Search for the file using the File name through [Files](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Files/9WZDNCRFJ3PL) app. If found follow steps said by [Luke](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/users/18949/luke-j) said in the [previous answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/12363/18061).
2. If your file is not found then it means that the recording is stored in the apps isolated memory which is Sandboxed. This means that you have have no way than to share the file from **within the application** itself.

Many audio recording apps have a separate section which lists the files you have recorded. From here you can directly share the audio file or save it to SDcard depending on the app. Once saved to SDcard you can follow *step 1* to share you recordings.

*Additional reference* :

1. [Learn how apps are sandboxed in Windowsphone : Security for Windows phone](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/ff402533(v=vs.105))